# Value first shows with null and after a second shows the correct value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why the value shows with null at the first second and after the first second shows the correct value...

I have the below method which in my bloc `Cubit` Class:

```
  CellsResponse cellResponse;

  String mcc = "";
  String mnc = "";
  StatefulElement _element;
  bool get mounted => _element != null;

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    CellsResponse cellsResponse;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      String platformVersion = await CellInfo.getCellInfo;
      final body = json.decode(platformVersion);

      cellsResponse = CellsResponse.fromJson(body);

      CellType currentCellInFirstChip = cellsResponse.primaryCellList[0];
      if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "LTE") {
        mcc =
            "LTE mcc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.lte.network.mcc.toString();

        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.lte.network.mnc.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "NR") {
        mcc =
            "NR mcc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.nr.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.nr.network.mnc.toString();
      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "WCDMA") {
        mcc = "WCDMA mcc = " +
            currentCellInFirstChip.wcdma.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.wcdma.network.mnc.toString();

      } else if (currentCellInFirstChip.type == "GSM") {
        mcc = currentCellInFirstChip.gsm.network.mcc.toString();
        mnc =
            "LTE mnc = " + currentCellInFirstChip.gsm.network.mnc.toString();

        // print('currentMCC = ' + mcc);
        // print('currentCqi = ' + mnc);
      }
    } on PlatformException {
      cellResponse = null;
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
      cellResponse = cellsResponse;
      emit(AppSetCellResponseState());
  }
```

as I call the value in the below class stateless widget:

```
                                          DataCell(
                                            CustomText(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                              text: cubit.mcc,
                                              color: goldDefaultColor,
                                            ),
                                          ),
```

So while I am trying to get the value in the build widget:

```
print('currentMCC is = ' + AppCubit.get(context).mcc);
```

it shows the value with null and after a second shows the correct value as the below in log:

```
I/flutter (23753): currentMCC is = 
I/flutter (23753): currentMCC is = 602
```

and this is the below full Screen class:

```
import 'package:airforce/shared/cubit/app_cubit.dart';
import 'package:airforce/shared/cubit/app_states.dart';
import 'package:airforce/shared/widgets/serving_cell_widget/gsm/servingCellTable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:airforce/shared/widgets/custom_text.dart';
import 'package:airforce/shared/styles/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SlotScreen extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('currentMCC is = ' + AppCubit.get(context).mcc);
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
          return Container(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.4),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: cubit.scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                              top: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              bottom: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            CustomText(
                              text: 'Sim information',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            LayoutBuilder(
                              builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'assets/images/vodafone-logo.png',
                                    ),
                                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.25,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: DataTable(
                                      headingRowHeight: 20,
                                      columnSpacing: 40,
                                      dataRowHeight: 20,
                                      columns: [
                                        DataColumn(
                                            label: CustomText(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                          text: 'OPERATOR',
                                        )),
                                        DataColumn(
                                          label: Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              CustomText(
                                                padding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                                text: 'vodafone',
                                                color: goldDefaultColor,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      rows: [
                                        DataRow(cells: [
                                          DataCell(Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              CustomText(
                                                text: 'MCC',
                                                padding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )),
                                          DataCell(
                                            CustomText(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                              text: cubit.mcc,
                                              color: goldDefaultColor,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ]),
                                        DataRow(cells: [
                                          DataCell(CustomText(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                            text: 'MNC',
                                          )),
                                          DataCell(CustomText(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                            text: '02',
                                            color: goldDefaultColor,
                                          )),
                                        ]),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                              top: Radius.circular(20.0),
                              bottom: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            CustomText(
                              text: 'Sim information',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            DataTable(
                              headingRowHeight: 20,
                              columnSpacing: 40,
                              dataRowHeight: 20,
                              columns: [
                                DataColumn(
                                    label: CustomText(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  text: 'Sim operator',
                                )),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      CustomText(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                        text: 'sim info',
                                        color: goldDefaultColor,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                              rows: [
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      CustomText(
                                        text: 'ICCID',
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                                  DataCell(
                                      CustomText(
                                    text: 'iccid',
                                    color: goldDefaultColor,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  )),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    CustomText(
                                      text: 'IMEI',
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(CustomText(
                                    text: '123456789',
                                    color: goldDefaultColor,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  )),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(CustomText(
                                    text: 'SIM IMSI',
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                  )),
                                  DataCell(CustomText(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                                    text: '123456789',
                                    color: goldDefaultColor,
                                  )),
                                ]),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                              top: Radius.circular(15.0),
                              bottom: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        ),
                        child: GSMServingCellTable(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                              top: Radius.circular(15.0),
                              bottom: Radius.circular(5.0)),
                        ),
                        child: GSMServingCellTable(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

it reads in the bloc cubit class fine, but when I am trying to call it in the screen I found this problem....

Comment: Try to use Stream in place of **initPlatformState**

Comment: @PrabhanshuTiwari Sorry but how can I use Stream :D?